# installing Pecl Oauth extension into a server

Tags: php, oauth, quickbooks-online

i was trying the apk of intuit SDK for QuickBooks Online. i successfully test this with my wamp localhost server cause i downloaded and installed Pecl Oauth extension on my wamp server. now, when i tried it on 1and1. i could not launch the log in when i clicked at the sign in with intuit button. i suspected that Pecl Oauth extension was not present at the server.

i was wondering if there is a way of including the Pecl Oauth extension on my server with the use of php.ini? if it is not, is there any other possible way.

i searched on the internet on how to do this but there is no link that i could find.

-thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact 1and1 and ask them to install it for you.

Alternatively, use this library (which doesn't require the PECL extension) and you'll be good to go:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php